# Can't get value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I've been doing a lot more Python than PHP recently so perhaps I've forgotten something important, but as far as I can see, this looks like it should work. What's actually wrong with it?

```
$form_settings = array('typeofzone' >= array('tm', 'tp', 'tc'),
                       'chargenum' >= array('pcn'));

$form_id = 'typeofzone';

// This echoes absolutely nothing
echo $form_settings[$form_id][0];
echo $form_settings[$form_id][1];
echo $form_settings[$form_id][2];
```

Comment: `>=` is a comparison operator; `=>` is the array assignment operator

Comment: https://3v4l.org/dBPeN is how your array looks like.

Comment: Oops haha, I'd never even used `>=` before yesterday so I totally missed that, I think I have a bit of muscle memory with the comparison way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong... you should use "=>" instead of ">="...

Answer (score 1):

```
$form_settings = array('typeofzone' >= array('tm', 'tp', 'tc'),
                       'chargenum' >= array('pcn'));
```

should be:

```
$form_settings = array('typeofzone' => array('tm', 'tp', 'tc'),
                       'chargenum' => array('pcn'));
```